# assigning a kubernetes ingress to a specific node

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to assign the ingress to a specific node?

I know that it is possible to assign a pod to a specific node using `nodeSelectors` but that is not a valid option for ingress pods according to the spec.

Comment: you can just run the pod on specific node, ingress will route the traffic to pod.  we can't configure ingress to route traffic to only one node.

Comment: Can you point to the doc you are refering to? Where are you running Kubernetes? What is the reason you feel you need to have the ingress or the ingress controller assigned to a node? These are all question that we would need to help you understand the system better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say. Ingress only works, if any of your nodes has an ingress controller, like nginx or traefik. Defining an ingress using the `Ingress` resource doesn't implicitly addresses a target node. Instead of this, you can create your ingress controller using `nodeSelector`, what makes sure, that these nodes definitely are connected to the services.

If you want to exclude other ingress controllers, you should annotate your ingress controllers and match them with annotations on ingress, like

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress-zone1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "zone1"
spec:
```

(check out [source](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/multiple-ingress-controllers))

Then you can match specific ingress controllers, which are in a zone to use the ingress on selected nodes

Answer (score 3):

`Ingress` is just a logical way to represent how to route traffic to service/pod. Regarding the question, `Ingress Controller` might be the right term on which you should check instead.

Read more here: [ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers). There's a possible chance `Ingress Controller pod` can be assigned to specific node.